# Msgbox not closing when WSH.Popup waits for certain time

Tags: excel, vba, wsh

I have an Excel file that opens automatically with Windows Scheduler. Also I have an `Auto_Open` sub to run a macro immediately. To avoid that every time it opens it starts running without a chance to modify it, I set up a `msgbox` that let me choose if the macro runs or not. However, I want Excel to automatically choose "Yes" after 10 seconds have passed, and I'm not able to get it. This is my code:

I have tried to place the seconds directly without a variable, I have also tried `Case -1` alone, yet nothing works.

```
Sub Auto_Open()

Set WSH = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
'cTime = 10 
BtnCode = WSH.Popup("¿Desea generar la consulta de vacaciones?", cTime, "Consulta", vbYesNo)

Select Case BtnCode
    Case vbYes
    Call consulta

    Case vbNo

    Case 1, -1
    Call consulta

    End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: You can use something like this. 

`Application.Wait Now + #0:00:01#
or (for Excel 2010 and later):

Application.Wait Now + #12:00:01 AM#`

Comment: But how would I make that, after the Popup shows, it stops waiting for an answer and starts to wait por this instruction? Because it is like stopped until I choose something, that's why I use WSH.Popup, because it has the option to set how many seconds would you like to wait before it continues.

Comment: i thing the below answer is more to what you need. You are right the popup will stop vba from executing until a button is pressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after a lot of research I managed to do what I want without a lot of issues.
First, I created a scrip (.vbs file) that contains the following:

```
Dim objExcel
Dim objWB

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = True
Set objWB = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("R:path\file.xlsm")
objExcel.Run "MyMacroName"
objWB.Save
objWB.Close False
objExcel.Quit
```

Now every time I run the script, the macro would run automatically. I have also set up a Windows Scheduler Event so it will run by itself with the script. In that way, I don't need a Popup to ask me if I want to run something, and the script would only run when the Event is triggered by the conditions set.

On the other hand, the Excel file itself is free from autorun when the workbook is opened, so any user can modify it without any problem.

Thanks to the people that helped me through this.

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to use a userform in combination with a module to run this. The UserForm would need to replace whatever you're doing with `Msgbox`. The code you'll need would look something like this:

USERFORM clode

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

'Run code for yes

'then
Unload Me

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
'run code for "no".

'then
Unload Me

End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"), "KeepItGoing"

End Sub
```

Then you can have it interact with an external module:

```
Sub launchSOMETHING()
'Run this first

UserForm1.Show

End Sub


Sub KeepItGoing()

If UserForm1.Visible = True Then
    MsgBox "BOOOOMO"
    Unload UserForm1


End If


End Sub
```

[You can see an example in this file here.](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AiO7_3PtXmZ9gftDLhhFy9sbRNyo3Q)

**UPDATED:** It appears that all macros will pause while `Msgbox` is open. In the below two procedures, you'll note that the second one won't be triggered until after the box is closed, even though it was supposed to run in 5 seconds.

```
Sub TestWhatMsgBoxDoes()

Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:5"), "someOtherMacro"
MsgBox "Everything is on hold?"



End Sub


Sub someOtherMacro()
Application.StatusBar = "The Second Macro has run at" & Now()


End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, I really want to know why the Case -1 is not working, because that's how  WSH.Popup should work. If there's no option, I will go for userforms.

Comment: Hello PGCodeRider. Thank you for your time in this answer. I have advanced in this issue and I'm still looking for an answer. First of all, it is not a MSGBOX command, it is a Windows Script (Popup), which has as argument _nSecondsToWait_. Therefore, it is a possibility to use it. I have found that it works perfectly if I run the macro when the workbook is Open, yet it won't work when the `Auto_Open` macro runs. So the only thing left is to know why does that happen.

Answer (score 0):

I think has to do with the "Call consulta" procedure, try use megbox to test it.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. It doesn't work either. It sends msgbox with vbyes and vbno, but the case -1 doesn't do anything after 10 seconds.